# How to write arguments in function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have been using `functions` but I am not able to tackle this.

What I have done is created a function, then made this to use the values provided by the document class or ids and do the work. Once work is done then just give the data back! It worked!

Now I want to make this function happen for two divs, the first function works good. The issue is with the second one. The function is correct, their is some other bug while writing the result.

Here is my code:

```
function time_untilCom(id) {
    var Time2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("time_" + 2).value);
    var curTime2 = new Date();
    var timeToWrite2 = "";
    var seconds2 = Math.floor((curTime2 - Time2) / (1000));
    if (seconds2 > 0 && seconds2 < 60) {// seconds..
        timeToWrite2 = seconds2 + " seconds ago";
        $('#update_' + 2).html(seconds2);
        $('#jstime_' + 2).html(timeToWrite2 + " <b>Time that was captured!</b>");
    }
}
```

If I use it as it is, it works! The issue comes when I try to replace these

`("time_" + 2)`, `("#update_" + 2)`, `("#jstime" + 2)` with `("time_" + id)`, `("#update_" + id)`, `("#jstime_" + id)`.

What i want to happen is that the function would be provided with a common ID that is applied throughout the `div` and use that ID, to get the value of time, convert it to seconds, do other stuff and then provide me with the result in the corresponding element with the id that was in the argument.

`function` works great, it do provide me with the result. But the issue is with the `id` its not being sent I guess. Or if is being sent then not being applied. What might be the issue here? And don't mind the `seconds` i have that covered too.

**I am really very sorry for short code:**

Pardon me, I was about to write the code for the `function` too. But electricity ran out!

Here is the code: `onload="time_untilCom('2')`, this is the way I am executing this.

And once in the main code, it will be executed like this: `onload="time_untilCom(@row.Id)` because I am using `ASP.NET Web Pages` I will be using the server side code to write the ID from Database. And will then user the ID throughtout the div to update the time!

Comment: `"time_"+2` should be `"time_2` ? I don't understand, `"time_"+2` I guess gives you `NAN`

Comment: It works. You will get `time_2` anyway, but it is just an unusual way of writing it

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: @steo, I am using `"time_" + 2` which would give me this: `time_2`, note that 2 would be replaced by the argument `id`. So its not 2 everytime. It can be 25 89 or anyother ID that the server would produce.

Comment: @devnull69, what would be a better way to write it then? :)

Comment: @Shomz, just editted the question :) Have a look

Comment: Added asp.net tag to the question

Comment: So any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you probably want to replace the second line

```
var Time2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("time_" + 2).value);
```

with

```
var Time2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById(id).value);
```

And at the end you can also use

```
$('#'+id).html(timeToWrite2 + " <b>Time that was captured!</b>");
```

Comment: No no brother, I want to write what I have written. The issue is just while I get the value from argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing "id" as an argument, but you never use it inside the function. My question is: In your example you are using `2` as appendix to id attributes. Is it the `2` (or other numbers respectively) that you want to have as the id parameter of the function?

Then you could just replace each `+ 2` in your code by `+ id`

```
function time_untilCom(id) {
  var Time2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("time_" + id).value);
  var curTime2 = new Date();
  var timeToWrite2 = "";
  var seconds2 = Math.floor((curTime2 - Time2) / (1000));
  if (seconds2 > 0 && seconds2 < 60) {// seconds..
    timeToWrite2 = seconds2 + " seconds ago";
    $('#update_' + id).html(seconds2);
    $('#jstime_' + id).html(timeToWrite2 + " <b>Time that was captured!</b>");
  }
}
```

EDIT: Please tell us where and how exactly do you call `time_untilCom`? Did you pass the id there?

Comment: You're right! The main thing was that I didn't want to write the function twice by just replacing `2` with `id`. So I just mentioned the issue. Yes 2 is what `id` is having. 2 will be replaced by any other ID that server would create for that div. Its not what I would create. The issue comes when I replace `2` with `id`. What I guess is that `id` is not being sent correctly. Because I donot get a responce in the divs, if there was error Atleast the divs would have been updated by an `error` text! I have editted the question, Have a look :)